# How to write to table with date column with DBI

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-dbi

I'm trying to append a dataframe to a sql server table using:

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(con_poc, "DEP_EVENTS", data_up, overwrite=FALSE, append = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
```

But I am getting an error on a column that is 'date' type in the database.

```
    Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22003: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Numeric value out of range
```

I previously formatted the column using  as.POSIXct(example_date) but this only seems to work for 'datetime' columns

Can anyone help?

Adding info:

```
DEP_EVENTS:
DATA_REGION (varchar(50), not null)
EVENT_ID(PK, bigint, not null)
EVENT_NAME(varchar(200), not null)
FORECAST_STATUS(varchar(50), not null)
FORECAST_CYCLE(date, not null)

data_up <- data.frame(DATA_REGION = "America",
                      EVENT_NAME = "shiny deal",
                      FORECAST_STATUS = "Plan of Record",
                      FORECAST_CYCLE = as.Date("2017-07-07"))

DBI::dbWriteTable(con_poc, "DEP_EVENTS", data_up, overwrite=FALSE, append = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)

Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22003: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Numeric value out of range
```

I'm not inserting the primary key as I get the following error when I try that

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc.cpp:1587: 23000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'DEP_EVENTS' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Also as requested:

```
str(data_up)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ DATA_REGION    : Factor w/ 1 level "America": 1
 $ EVENT_NAME     : Factor w/ 1 level "shiny deal": 1
 $ FORECAST_STATUS: Factor w/ 1 level "Plan of Record": 1
 $ FORECAST_CYCLE : Date, format: "2017-07-07"
```

I also tried changing the factor columns to character but no change in the error.

Comment: could you try formatting your date object with `format(example_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")`?

Comment: Tried that but it is giving the same error, it converted the column to a character type?

Comment: I usually use `RODBCext` instead of `DBI`, and converting dates and datetimes to strings was required up until a recent release.  I didn't know if it was similar in `DBI`.

Comment: Did you try `as.Date()`?

Comment: I see you opened a bounty. Had you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a few rows of your R dataframe with datatypes (`str()`) and the SQL Server table's schema we would have gladly helped two days ago. Please provide those now.

Comment: @Parfait Apologies, I have added more information

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have tried both `as.POSIXct()` and `as.Date()` but no luck with either yet

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error is about the date column? I would expect an error like `Invalid date format` if the problem is within the date column. Guessing around: Your columns get mixed up, and it fails inserting a string value into the EVENT_ID column. I would try: Remove the auto-generated primary key column, make it (for the test) a normal bigint column, try to insert all values of the table. Or the other way round: Remove all columns except the date column to verify the problem is really within the date column. As said: guessing around.

Comment: I have tried sqlSave from the RODBC package and also encountered problems. It was trying to insert into the primary key column. Is there a way using either sqlSave or dbWriteTable to skip the autoincrement primary key column?

Comment: In your `data.frame()` try adding the arg, `stringsAsFactors=False` as factors may be treated as numeric during database insert. Also, is *Event_ID* an auto-generated number, specifically *Identity(1,1)* field?

Comment: I've just tried the posted code using both the `odbc` and `RSQLServer` packages to connect to SQL Server, and it works fine in both cases. Which package are you using? Which operating system? Which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Using RODBC you can insert into the primary key column by prefacing your `sqlSave()` command with a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT = ON` statement. For example:

```
con = odbcConnect(MY_DSN)
sqlQuery(con,'SET IDENTITY_INSERT DEP_EVENTS ON')
sqlSave(con, DEP_EVENTS, rownames = FALSE, append = 
        TRUE, verbose = FALSE, fast = FALSE)        
sqlQuery(con,'SET IDENTITY_INSERT DEP_EVENTS OFF')
close(con)
```